# react-native-video is not playing in video in the flatList while single video outside flatlist is playing

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I am using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video) in my sample project to render videos in the flatlist. problem i am facing is video items are not playing in flatlist when i put same video component outside flatlist , it is working fine.
Also i did flatlist optimization accordingly .
please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

I have to implement the same thing and it works for me perfectly.

if possible you can share your code, I will help you.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you do it?

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Can you show me the code..? I can help you...